# Database Multiple Table Join Queries

Tags: database, join, qsqlquery

I really don't know what queries to be combined using these table to achieve my coressponding output please assist me

Table 1

w_ref   t_id   q_id  qty

110     111    500   1

111     112    500   2

112     113    500   3

Table 2

t_id q_id  material-x  material-y material_id

111  500      14          15          7

112  500      18          18          7

113  500      10          11          8

Table 3

id   material_name

7    abc
 8    def

I expect that joining table output like this

Output

w_ref   qty  material-x   material-y  material_name

110     1      14          15           abc

111     2      18          07           abc

112     3      10          11           def

Comment: is it SQL or MYSQL ? What have you done so far?

Comment: this is for MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a SQL of a `INNER JOIN`. This will give you a basic understanding from the results given.

```
SELECT a.w_ref, a.t_id, a.q_id, a.qty, b.material-x FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.t_id = a.t_id;
```

However their is very little of what you're trying to achieve and should not just post a question asking someone to sort it. Maybe add what you have tried so far and what outcomes you have had.